# Borrar Production track de google play console

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

Acabo de publicar un app en playstore, pero la publiqué en Production track y quería que por lo pronto estara en Closed tracks, en versión alpha para que solo fuera descargada por los testers.

¿Hay alguna opción que me permita deshábilitar el Production track para posteriormente ponerla en producción?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

**En este caso si se publico no hay forma de regresar a Beta o Alpha, si no la deseas en Produción la opción sería anularla (unpublish) y posteriormente publicar en Alpha o Beta.**

Para anular la publicación de tu aplicación ve a https://play.google.com/apps/publish/:

• Seleccione una aplicación.

• Selecciona Presencia en la tienda (Store presence) > Precios y distribución (Pricing & Distribution).

• En la sección "Disponibilidad de la aplicación" (App Availability ), selecciona Anular publicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora para tener tu app en distribución Alpha o Beta tendrías que subirla nuevamente con un versionCode mayor a la que creaste previamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]